# Subset by first and last value per group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R with two columns **temp** and **timeStamp**. The data has **temp** values regularly. A portion of dataframe looks like-

[image]

I have to create line chart showing changes in temp over time. As can be seen here, **temp** values remain the same for several **timeStamp**. Having these repeating value increases the size of data file and I want to remove them. So the output should look like this-

[image]

Showing just the values where there is a change.
Cannot think of a way to get this think done in R. Any inputs in the right direction would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'temp', we subset the first and last observation (`.SD[c(1L, .N)]`) per each group.  If there is only a single value per group, we take the row as such (`else .SD`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(.N>1) .SD[c(1L, .N)] else .SD, by =temp]
#    temp val
#1: 22.50   1
#2: 22.50   4
#3: 22.37   5
#4: 22.42   6
#5: 22.42   7
```

---

Or a `base R` option with `duplicated`.  We check the `duplicated` values in 'temp' (output is a logical vector), and also check the duplication from the reverse side (`fromLast=TRUE`).  Use `&` to find the elements that are `TRUE` in both cases, negate (`!`) and subset the rows of 'df1'.

```
df1[!(duplicated(df1$temp) & duplicated(df1$temp,fromLast=TRUE)),]
#   temp val
#1 22.50   1
#4 22.50   4
#5 22.37   5
#6 22.42   6
#7 22.42   7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(temp=c(22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.37,22.42, 22.42), val=1:7)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I group by temp, there are some temp values that are same as in the group but occurring at a later time (after some variation in temp), so this would not be helpful.

I am therefore running a loop over all values and selecting only those values where there is a change in temp into a new data frame.

Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @ZeeshanAKhan It was based on the example you showed.  If it is not the expected output, you should change your example and expected output.  Also, consider to post a dput output instead of an image

Comment: If you create an id column and group by id and temp, they will then be unique throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
# Toy data
df <- data.frame(time = seq(20), temp = c(rep(60, 5), rep(61, 7), rep(59, 3), rep(60, 5)))

# Now filter for the first and last rows and ones bracketing a temperature change
df %>% filter(temp!=lag(temp) | temp!=lead(temp) | time==min(time) | time==max(time))

  time temp
1    1   60
2    5   60
3    6   61
4   12   61
5   13   59
6   15   59
7   16   60
8   20   60
```

If the data are grouped by a third column (id), just add `group_by(id) %>%` before the filtering step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I group by temp, there are some temp values that are same as in the group but occurring at a later time (after some variation in temp), so this would not be helpful.

I am therefore running a loop over all values and selecting only those values where there is a change in temp into a new data frame.

Thanks for your response :)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. You don't need to group by temp.

Comment: A separate id column can help with that